# Pulling from another website

Tags: php, html, dom, curl, xpath

Im trying to pull a span class from one website to another but can't seem to make it work. Is it possible to use curl to get a single word from a different website?

Whats the proper syntax for a span class? With my code I receive the warning:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/uptickgather.php on line 25
```

My code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://quotes.wsj.com/UEPS');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$html = curl_exec($ch); // the whole document (in string) goes in here
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html); // load it
libxml_clear_errors();
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom); 

$class = $xpath->query('//[@class="cr_info info_price price_l"]//');
echo $class->nodeValue . ' ';
?>
```

Line 25 is:

```
echo $class->nodeValue . ' ';
```

So far I have tried to change the format of the query to work with the @ syntax. Thus I tried using a single slash, although as I understand it, double slash would show all attributes with the name

```
"cr_info info_price price_l"
```

I also tried to use the following:

```
$class = $xpath->query('//[@class="cr_info info_price price_l"]//');
```

However, I cannot seem to make it work. Does anyone with more experience in xpath/curl have any advice on how to fix this?

Edit: when I use var dump it looks like:

```
object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }
```

But I'm trying to get back into coding, and am completely lost. Can anyone help?

Comment: So where's line 25?  Is the DOMDocument object or the CURL object causing the error?  What debugging tactics have you tried so far?

Comment: what is it supposed to echo? let me know I will help you scrap this html

Comment: Its supposed to echo the price of a stock.

Comment: Have you checked $class? The xquery function will return false on failure (so $class will be boolean, not an object). On success, it returns a DOMNodeList, not a simple object. You need to use the proper getattribute methods.

Comment: Kainaw, you lost me, sorry I'm new to this. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: @user3517904 What do you get when you `var_dump` $class. I'm betting @kainaw is correct and that is in fact false. You should be checking for false anyway since it is a documented possible return value.

Comment: @Dan I get "object(DOMNodeList)#3 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) }"

Comment: Got it: it was the syntax of the query. Made it say ` $table_row = $xpath->query('//span[@class="helpContent-marker"]'); ` and it worked. Thanks for the pointers all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to combine the 2 following classes to pull information from another website:

Pull info from any HTML tag, contents or tag attribute: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Easy to handle curl, supports POST requests: https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class

So, in your example:

```
//download and include the 2 classes:
include('path/to/curl.php');
include('path/to/simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://quotes.wsj.com/UEPS';

$curl = new Curl;
$html = str_get_html($curl->get($url)); //pull all html of a website
$span = $html->find('span[class="cr_info info_price price_l"]',0)->plaintext; //find span tag that contains the following class, 0 means that it is first element that matches tag span and that class, plaintext means it will remove tags leaving only text within tag    
echo $span; //contents of span, e.g. $ 10.811 USD
```